# "Error running timer `font-latex-jit-lock-force-redisplay'" in LaTeX mode

Tags: latex, font-lock

Since an upgrade to GNU Emacs 24.4.1, I

```
Error running timer `font-latex-jit-lock-force-redisplay': (wrong-number-of-arguments (2 . 2) 3) [N times]
```

where `N` in my observations ranges from single digits to `240`.

`C-h f font-latex-jit-lock-force-redisplay` says only

```
Compatibility for Emacsen not offering `jit-lock-force-redisplay'.
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a following redefinition of [`font-latex-jit-lock-force-redisplay`](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=16879) that appears to solve my problem.  I put the following into my `.emacs` file:

```
(require 'font-latex)

(defun font-latex-jit-lock-force-redisplay (buf start end)
  "Compatibility for Emacsen not offering `jit-lock-force-redisplay'."
    ;; The following block is an expansion of `jit-lock-force-redisplay'
    ;; and involved macros taken from CVS Emacs on 2007-04-28.
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (let ((modified (buffer-modified-p)))
    (unwind-protect
        (let ((buffer-undo-list t)
          (inhibit-read-only t)
          (inhibit-point-motion-hooks t)
          (inhibit-modification-hooks t)
          deactivate-mark
          buffer-file-name
          buffer-file-truename)
          (put-text-property start end 'fontified t))
      (unless modified
        (restore-buffer-modified-p nil))))))
```

The first line was necessary, I suppose, because otherwise `font-latex.el` is only loaded when the first `.tex` file is visited and overwrites the definition from `.emacs`.

Comment: You can just upgrade your AUCTeX version as well, this [has been fixed upstream](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=5b5ef6eeb0468c273a329a05d31b3788fd46b5d7) long time ago.

Comment: @wasamasa with pleasure :-)